# How to throttle API requests by parameter in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, rate-limiting

I have an API like this:

ActionResult GetReport(Guid id)

Now we do serve data from the cache if available. If not, we fill the cache (by id) and then return from it - this however is a very long operation and while we are in the midst of doing this, we want any more incoming calls with the same id to "wait" until we populate the cache.

What is the best approach to doing this? (We do have a blob-cache-store that is accessible by all our docker container instances).

I have seen this blog on [Rate Limiting in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-7) but none of the techniques there seem to have a solution for my problem.

Comment: What you're describing isn't really "rate-limiting" - because you aren't blocking/preventing excessive requests from being served - instead you're _coalescing_ multiple requests to be served by the same result. You can do this with a `ConcurrentDictionary<Guid,Task>` and then `await` the `Task` from the dict, if any.

Comment: That sounds like a solution! Would it be possible to set this up as an attribute for an endpoint somehow? That way it would be easy to slap this on new and existing endpoints easily.